# how to prepare own dataset for CNN

Tags: tensorflow

I am building a CNN model to classify own dataset in python using `tensorflow 2`. How should i prepare my dataset in the directory to load it to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the train dataset and test dataset, extract them into 2 different folders named as “train” and “test”. The train folder should contain ‘n’ folders each containing images of respective classes. For example, in the Dog vs Cats dataset, the train folder should have 2 folders, namely “Dogs” and “Cats” containing respective images inside them. The same should be done for the test folder.

Then, you should use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` and its `flow_from_directory` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I call the dataset directory?

Comment: you can give it as an argument to the flow_from_directory function.

Comment: Could you please give an example. i tried to put the path of the file but it doesnt work

Comment: put the path of the directory

Comment: in my answer, like you will put 'train' directory and then, it will fetch all the data.

Comment: How to create the mask of the train and test images?